eas device:create - Missing iosUrlScheme in provided options: {}
When running eas device:create I get the following error:
google-sign-in without Firebase config plugin: Missing iosUrlScheme in provided options: {}
Error: device:create command failed.
I am configuring the iosUrlScheme using eas.json and .env files:
    '@react-native-google-signin/google-signin',
    {
      iosUrlScheme: process.env.REVERSED_GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
    },

.env
#GOOGLE SIGN IN
REVERSED_GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID = com.googleusercontent.apps.EXAMPLE
eas.json
"preview": {
  "distribution": "internal",
  "env": {
    "REVERSED_GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID": "com.googleusercontent.apps.EXAMPLE

